# How do I use the input from a text box as a url that can be opened on a browser (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net

I'm (almost) completely brand new to coding  and I need some guidance on how to do something in Visual Basic. I'm also sorry if anything that I am saying makes no sense, like I said, brand new.

All tutorials and guides that I have seen so far have used a preset url, something like

```
Private Sub BSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bSearch.Click
    Process.Start("www.google.com")

End Sub
```

This would take you to google.com

However I would like the url to be determined by something that the user has provided in a Text Box. So that it may function like a web browser. Once again I am sorry if what I'm saying makes no sense.

Comment: What you're asking makes perfect sense but it shows no effort at all on your own behalf. You're asking us how to get text from a `TextBox`. I can't imagine anything easier to find out for yourself. Any research on how `TextBoxes` are used would show you that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you could solve your problem.

1. Google Process.Start https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=net-5.0 is the link to check. Microsoft Docs is where you can see the details. I know is is hard to read at the beginning but you will learn.
2. Ignore the more complicated overloads and look at Start(String)
3. Ahha! `Process.Start(String)` can take a single `String` as a parameter.
4. Now let's look at `TextBox.Text` Again with Google we find https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.textbox.text?view=net-5.0
5. Ahha! The `.Text` property is a `String`. We have a match!
6. Now we can write

   `Process.Start(TextBox1.Text)`

because `Process.Start` is expecting a `String` and the `Text` property of a `TextBox` is a `String`.

Hopefully, the user has typed in something that can be recognized as a URL.